# draw ball in canvas is not appearing in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I try a simple game using javascript that is Dino Run and I want to add another obstacle using canvas to draw a ball.

This is the body in my index.html

```
<div id="board" style="background-position: 0px; position: relative;">
      <div id="area" style="position:relative">
        <div id="dino"></div>
        <div id="box" style="margin-left: 600px"></div>
        <canvas id="movingBallCanvas" width="20" height="20" style="position: absolute; top:170px;"></canvas>
   </div>
 </div>
```

and here is the code in javascript for the ball I want to draw

```
 var movingBallCanvas = document.getElementById("movingBallCanvas");
 var movingBallContext = movingBallCanvas.getContext("2d");

      function drawMovingBall(x, y) {
        movingBallContext.clearRect(0, 0, movingBallCanvas.width, movingBallCanvas.height);
        movingBallContext.fillStyle = "red";
        movingBallContext.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
      }

      var ballX = 800; // Initial position
      var ballY = 170;

      function animateMovingBall() {
        if (!isGameover) {
          ballX -= 1; // Move the ball to the left
          if (ballX < -20) {
            ballX = 800; // Reset position when it goes off the screen
          }

          // Check for collision with the dino
          if (
            dino.offsetTop + 50 >= ballY &&
            dino.offsetLeft + 50 >= ballX &&
            dino.offsetTop + 50 <= ballY + 20 &&
            dino.offsetLeft <= ballX + 20
          ) {
            gameOver();
          } else {
            // Keep moving
            drawMovingBall(ballX, ballY);
            requestAnimationFrame(animateMovingBall);
          }
        }
      }

      // Initialize the animation
      animateMovingBall();
```

I thought there was an error in the order of placing the canvas on the body html so that the ball was drawn behind another object, but I couldn't find a solution when I moved the canvas to the top amongst the dino and the box. I put the initial position for the ball in `ballX = 800` because I want the ball starting from the outside of the layer and also put the `ballY = 170` because I want the ball's height is the same as the box.

here's the css of the box, the box is starting from outside the layer

```
#box{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    background: url('images/redbox.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin-left: 600px;
}
```

Is there another problem I havent noticed yet? I'm really confused where's wrong because it returns no error. I already put the getElementById and the context, but still didnt give any solution. Please help me, thank you so much!

Comment: The provided code is incomplete as it references dino, isGameover, or gameOver(), which were not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problems are that the canvas element is only 20 x 20 pixels so drawing balls with an x value that is greater or equal to 20 doesn't show anything.

For the purposes of demonstration below, I've increased to canvas size to  620 x 320 pixels, supplied the `isGame`boolean and `gameOver` function, and made the `#dino` a colored square instead of an image. FYI, it would have been better to have included runnable code in the question.

Running the code shows there are some obvious issues that need to looked at immediately, and I assume parts of the game have yet to be written, both of which I am leaving you to look into as part of development.

```js
"use strict";
const isGameover = false; // testing
function gameOver() {
  isGameover=true;
}
var movingBallCanvas = document.getElementById("movingBallCanvas");
 var movingBallContext = movingBallCanvas.getContext("2d");

      function drawMovingBall(x, y) {
        movingBallContext.clearRect(0, 0, movingBallCanvas.width, movingBallCanvas.height);
        movingBallContext.fillStyle = "red";
        movingBallContext.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
      }

      var ballX = 600; // Initial position
      var ballY = 170;

      function animateMovingBall() {
        if (!isGameover) {
          ballX -= 1; // Move the ball to the left
          if (ballX < -20) {
            ballX = 600; // Reset position when it goes off the screen
          }

          // Check for collision with the dino
          if (
            dino.offsetTop + 50 >= ballY &&
            dino.offsetLeft + 50 >= ballX &&
            dino.offsetTop + 50 <= ballY + 20 &&
            dino.offsetLeft <= ballX + 20
          ) {
            gameOver();
          } else {
            // Keep moving

            drawMovingBall(ballX, ballY);
            requestAnimationFrame(animateMovingBall);
          }
        }
      }

      // Initialize the animation
      animateMovingBall()
```

```css
#box{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    /* background: url('images/redbox.png');
       background-size: 100% 100%;
    */
    background-color: pink; /* no image available */
    margin-left: 600px;
}
canvas {
background-color: #00800020;
}
```

```html
<div id="board" style="background-position: 0px; position: relative;">
      <div id="area" style="position:relative">
        <div id="dino"></div>
        <div id="box" style="margin-left: 600px"></div>
        <canvas id="movingBallCanvas" width="620" height="320" style="position: absolute; top:170px;"></canvas>
   </div>
 </div>
```

*Please click the full screen button to see the overall result when running the code*.